# oAuth and Codeigniter with MongoDB

Tags: codeigniter, oauth

I am using the oAuth library for Codeigniter made by Alex Bilbie. It is made for MySQL.
Has anyone used it with MongoDB? I will try to "convert" it to MongoDB but there are som many files in the repo and only few of them is needed for the server setup.

Does anyone know if there is a ready made Mongodb of this repo and / or which files that
is the bare minimum for a server only setup?

Repo:

https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server

Thankful for all input!

Comment: I haven't seen one, but I would happily use it if you decided to "convert" it.

Comment: I would be good to know which files that are "core" for the oAuth server. Many of the files are used for the client. When I know which files that are server only I can start "converting".

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but it might be what you're looking for.

Funnily enough Alex has already created a mongodb active record driver for CI. You will probably have a much easier time converting it to using this than anything else I'm guessing.

Blog
http://archive.alexbilbie.com/2010/04/17/a-codeigniter-active-record-library-for-mongodb/

Bitbucket
https://bitbucket.org/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongo-library/wiki/Home

If you do get around to making a conversion github it and link here please :)