# Is there a mongodb-backed user authentication library for codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, codeigniter-2, php-mongodb

I need a Codeigniter login library for user authentication. I use MongoDB as my database.

I have gone through some of the recommended libraries like [Ion Auth](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Ion_Auth_-_Lightweight_Auth_System), [Tank Auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/), [DX Auth](http://dexcell.shinsengumiteam.com/dx_auth/) etc. but all use mysql databases.

Is there a recommended library which uses mongodb as a database?

I began converting one of the libraries above from mysql to mongodb insetions but it is getting too complex- many changes are needed and think I will end up messing it. Need help on a good library using mongodb.

Comment: have you made any progress? I'm going to use Tank Auth for a new project and I'm thinking of modifying it to use MongoDB. Worst case I just have mysql handle the user accounts and let mongodb deal w/ everything else.

Comment: Yes I have created a login library using MongoDb, based on Tank Auth library. I will post it to GitHub soon and give the link here

Comment: Has Tank Auth been updated recently? Seems development has stopped and everyone is using Ben's code.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth (Ion Auth) has now a MongoDB support. See the README section on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any use it natively, but before you go converting things yourself you may want to check out this answer I made to a similar (non-dupe) question: [oAuth and Codeigniter with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687470/oauth-and-codeigniter-with-mongodb/7806154#7806154)

It will get you started on a conversion with little work needed. I'd also recommend using ion auth, tank auth is huge and DX auth is outdated.